# Bitrix24 Reopen calling popup window

Tags: telephony, bitrix

In bitrix24 when I pickup call using Phone device and refresh the web page I lost the popup answering window.Now I want to reopen the lost popup window.
Please suggest how I to achieve this

Answer (score 1):

If you know the callId, you can use javascript library

```
BX24.callMethod('telephony.externalcall.show', {CALL_ID: $callId, USER_ID: $userThatShouldSeeWindowId}, function(res){

});
```

or rest api

```
https://your_portal.bitrix24.com/rest/telephony.externalcall.show.json?CALL_ID=callId&USER_ID=userThatShouldSeeWindowId&auth=access_token
```

Docs:
https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/rest_help/scope_telephony/telephony/telephony_externalcall_show.php